# Java Script Hover on box with picture and text + switch colors

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, hover

I'm trying to make a hover on box with picture and text.

I would like to force JS/css to change color of the box (div) and text when mouse pointer is on box ( as on image on link below ). So there should be hover on image + at the same time text on the image + change color of text and icons - calendar + comments ( or switch icons for icons with white color ).

I tried to make hover with SVG filter and css opacity ( for image hover is working fine ), but there is problem with text color and of course with additional text on image. Also I tried Java Script with mouseover, but still nothing...

image how it should work:

```
http://szkolajezykowakola.vxm.pl/st.jpg
```

**simple div**

```
<div class="boxentry">
```

**Css - test for grey scale**

```
.boxentry:hover {
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); 
  filter: gray; 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}
```

Comment: copy your sample code, causing the issue, to jsfiddle.net and then save it and share in your question